# centering 2 buttons on the div bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do this mockup...

[image]

... and I came to the point where I need to put these 2 buttons on the image. I managed to put one button, but the second one is not working. This is the code for first button.

```css
#img_container {
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
}
.button {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:50%;
  right:50%;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  margin:0px -100px -15px 0px;
  background-color: rgb(246, 175, 228);
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 4.5px 7.794px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.094);;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div id="img_container" class=" "text-center col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <img src="img/homepicture.jpg"/>
    <button class="button">lazybop</button><br>
    <button class="button1">see the products</button>
</div>
```

Then I tried to use the same code, but just decrease the number of bottom property to 40%, but it still remains in the same place.

```
.button1 {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:40%;
  right:50%;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: rgb(246, 175, 228);
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 4.5px 7.794px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.094);;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: You have an additional double quotes in `class=" "text-center col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"`

Answer (score 0):

You had a mistake in class

```
class=**" "**text-center col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="img_container" class="text-center col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <img src="img/homepicture.jpg"/>
    <button class="button">lazybop</button><br>
    <button class="button1">see the products</button>
</div>
```

Remove a single " in class or copy paste the above code

http://quandaflow.com/category/website/css/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it :

Replace the `<img>` with a background-image on the container, and define the height of this container with the height of the device with `100vh`.

```
<div id="img_container" class="text-center col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div id="button-container">
           <button class="button button1">lazybop</button>
           <button class="button button2">see the products</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

```
#img_container {
  background-image: url("http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  height:100vh;
  position:relative;

  /* Flexbox part, to align the button vertically : */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

#button-container{
  position:relative;
}
.button {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: rgb(246, 175, 228);
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 4.5px 7.794px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.094);;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.button1{
  margin-left:-100px;
  z-index:10;
}

.button2{
  top:50px;
}
```

Here's a JsFiddle : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/awsca429/3/)

**NOTE** : To center the buttons vertically, I used flexbox. 
But if you dont want to use flexbox, you can replace it with transform :

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```